# Is it ok if my passport is a little bent?

Tags: passports, damaged-passports

The side pocket of my pants puts pressure on the passport.

It looks a bit like this (but not this much):
[image]
<sub>[source](https://freedesignfile.com/upload/2012/10/201209234_designfile55.jpg)</sub>

Is this ok?
I intend to continue using that pocket.

Comment: What nationality is that? If it is a non-biometric passport (Indian...) will work just as fine. A bent biometric passport may encounter some issues due to the chip being in the cover, but you can easily check that your chip still works by reading it with your phone

Comment: Biometric regular passport. "check that your chip still works by reading it with your phone" how?

Comment: ReadID Me ([iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/readid-me/id1463949991), [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.innovalor.nfciddocshowcase))

Comment: After over a year in a money belt while I backpacked around the world, my passport was in a very sorry state but no one ever objected to it.  However, it was long ago and biometric was not even a dream yet.  In those, the Irish passport was big and hard bound.  Its spine had cracked.

Comment: @NicolasFormichella the chip isn't necessarily in the cover.

Comment: When my passports have been in the back pocket of my trousers for a couple of hours, it gets a (very) slight bend (like shown), then I just remember to put it with the other side out the next time, then it gets pressured the other way. In the end it practically evens out, and I didn't have (or expect) problems the last time I used (the chip in) it.

Answer (score 2):

80s, our passports had a distinct curve from being worn under clothing 24/7, it never caused an issue.  It's possible things have changed since, though.